# JSTL fmt:formatDate with locale dependent pattern

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, jstl-functions

In a JSP page I have to display some dates, but none of the available date formats (short, medium or long) suits me.

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${someDate}" type="date" dateStyle="short"/>
<fmt:formatDate value="${someDate}" type="date" dateStyle="medium"/>
<fmt:formatDate value="${someDate}" type="date" dateStyle="long"/>
```

I have to resort to a specified pattern:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${someDate}" type="date" pattern="dd-MM/yyyy"/>
```

But, the pattern itself is locale dependent, I mean, I want to load the pattern from the message bundle. How can I do it?

I tried

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${someDate}" type="date" pattern="<fmt:message key='date.format.short'/>"/>
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess you want a German format? If so, set locale to German, then the dateStyle might suit better.

Comment: @BalusC per your suggestion, the problem would remain unchanged, since for one locale (say cs) I would map another one (say de) and so on, so the "locale to set to" would be locale-dependent. No, I don't want a German format. That pattern there in my post is just an example. It could be virtually anything (any valid pattern, of course). I just want it to be locale-dependent. I'll edit the question to let it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `<c:set>` tag to store the value of the pattern.

Something like this would do what you want:

```
<c:set var="myPattern"><fmt:message key="date.format.short" /></c:set>

<fmt:formatDate value="${someDate}" type="date" pattern="${myPattern}" />
```

Or better yet, as pointed by @Sachin, use the `var` attribute:

```
<fmt:message key="date.format.short" var="${myPattern}"/>

<fmt:formatDate value="${someDate}" type="date" pattern="${myPattern}" />
```

Comment: This is simplier one

<fmt:message key='date.format.short' var='pattrn'/>
<fmt:formatDate value="${someDate}" type="date" pattern="${pattrn}" />

Comment: that's correct. I worked recently with JSF `<h:outputFormat>` that doesn't define a `var` attribute, and I got confused.